# vue 2 filter not working after change the value via v-edit-dialog

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-data-table

After changing the value by clicking on the field, the value is displayed without the currency filter. the template is in a data-table.

```html
<template v-slot:item.price="{item}">
  <v-edit-dialog
      large
      :return-value.sync="item.price"
  >
    {{ item.price | toCurrency}}
    <template v-slot:input>
      <v-text-field
          v-model="item.price"
          label="Edit price"
          single-line
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
  </v-edit-dialog>
</template>
```

here the filter:

```
Vue.filter('toCurrency', function (value: number) {
  if (typeof value !== "number") {
    return value;
  }
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('eu-EU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR'
  });
  return formatter.format(value);
});
```

Comment: if a filter doesn't work, it would help to post the code for that filter.  please read [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

after changing, string was given even though v-text-input had an type of number.

```
Vue.filter('toCurrency', function (value: number) {
  if (typeof value !== "number") {
    if(typeof parseFloat(value) !== "number")
    return value;
  }
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('eu-EU', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR'
  });
  return formatter.format(value);
});
```